# Display X Axis at Top of Plotly Plot in R Shiny Instead of Bottom?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

How do I display the x axis at the top of a Plotly horizontal bar plot instead of at the bottom? Showing the x axis at both the top and bottom would also be ok. The plot will be displayed in R Shiny and must be Plotly not ggplotly. Thanks!

Example from https://plot.ly/r/horizontal-bar-charts/:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(x = c(20, 14, 23), 
y = c('giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'), 
type = 'bar', 
orientation = 'h')
```

EDIT: HubertL provided a solution (thanks!) that puts the x axis at the top but it then overlaps with the chart title. My fault for not specifying that I am using a title. Is there a way to get the x axis title and x axis ticks to not overlap the plot title?

```
plot_ly(x = c(20, 14, 23), 
        y = c('giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'), 
        type = 'bar', 
        orientation = 'h') %>%
   layout(xaxis = list(side ="top", 
          title = "EXAMPLE X AXIS TITLE"), 
          title = "EXAMPLE PLOT TITLE")
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `side ="top"` in the `layout.xaxis`

```
plot_ly(x = c(20, 14, 23), 
        y = c('giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'), 
        type = 'bar', 
        orientation = 'h') %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(side ="top" ) )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That moves the x axis up. I'm happy to mark it answered but it isn't quite working right for me. When I use your solution the plot title, x axis title, and x axis ticks overlap. I'll edit my question to be more specific - let me know if this is not what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: Good! So please mark it answered and ask another question

Comment: To increase space above the plot and avoid title overlap, add `margin` to the `layout` eg. `margin=list(t=150, l=100)`