# Shifting the Position of X-Axis in a ggplot bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, plotly, ggplotly

The given script creates a horizontal bar plot using ggplot2 package. I want to shift the x-axis details and label on top of the chart. Please help.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
time <- c("A","B","C")
total_bill <- c(12,34,23)
dat <- data.frame(time,total_bill)
p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "#3399ff") +
coord_flip()
ggplotly(p)
```

[image: Bar Plot Capture]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display X Axis at Top of Plotly Plot in R Shiny Instead of Bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034368/display-x-axis-at-top-of-plotly-plot-in-r-shiny-instead-of-bottom)

Comment: @AndreElrico, Hi, thanks for replying, the package used is in your question is plotly, my plot has been made using ggplot2. Kindly help.

Comment: So the suggested layout function does not work? Can you get your plot using plot_ly() like in the mentioned question?

Comment: ggplot2 is a mandatory package that I am working on, I am afraid but I can't change the package for a minor change in the plot, please help.

Comment: Well I give it an upvote and hope you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image]If it is not necessary for you to use the ggplotly() function, you could try:

```
library(ggplot2)
time <- c("A","B","C")
total_bill <- c(12,34,23)
dat <- data.frame(time,total_bill)
p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill = "#3399ff") +
  coord_flip()
p + scale_y_continuous(position = "top")
```